# which browser gives best performance on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, performance, browser

I am using ubuntu 16.04. Can anyone give me suggestion which browser gives better performance. Recently I am using firefox (44.0) : It's good, but any  suggestion for another browser ?

Comment: 2 issues with your question: 1. Ubuntu 15.04 has gone EOL, so we don't support it anymore; consider upgrading to 16.04. 2. You need to define "best" experience: your "best" is different from everyone else's "best".

Comment: I have upgraded my ubuntu version and also modified question.

Comment: Another issue: browser are free to use. Why not download them all and try them so you can decide yourself? I use often 3 at the same time myself. FF49 is better than FF44. Vivaldi is nice too.

Comment: I think this is not feasible solution . Download all and manually check is also time consuming because there is a long list of browsers . Better is to ask a question , different people are using different browsers , they can easily describe their experience .

Answer (score 4):

I appreciate Google Chrome, primarily for its amazing syncing capabilities and reliable ad blocking extensions. It runs each tab as a different process, and is very fast in Ubuntu.

I heard firefox is reliable as well, and might have a bit more support than Chrome in the Linux realm (since Ubuntu ships with firefox).

Many other browsers seem to be lacking in features/compatibility/workability in all websites. For example, Chrome runs flash perfectly well with it's in-built flash. Firefox can run flash as well, but many other browsers (Midori for example) have trouble with flash.

Whichever browser you do choose, be sure it passes the most recent [Acid Test](http://acid3.acidtests.org/) with flying colors and 100/100. This will ensure your browsing experience is at its best.

Comment: You can read more about the Acid Test [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acid3). You can usually improve the performance of your browser to make it to 100% if its only missing a few tests. In any case, it's running pretty well.

Answer (score 2):

i would say firefox but u can try chromium and midori web browser ty

Answer (score 0):

as default configuration Canonical runs Firefox on Ubuntu which is so powerful and amazing but there is something to be considered that there is a built-in browser for Ubuntu which is Browser that which i found it so good.